# Tapestry: How to redirect deprecated URLs to an error page

Tags: apache, web-applications, jboss, tapestry

I have legacy web application built using apache Tapestry. I have deprecated most of the application's functionality except few pages. I want this application to be running in production, but I want to redirect deprecated pages/URLs to some error page with 404 error code. Where should I configure it? I have web.xml and jboss-web.xml. Do I need to do it in some Tapestry configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contribute a RequestFilter to the RequestHandler service, i.e. in your AppModule:

```
public void contributeRequestHandler(
              OrderedConfiguration<RequestFilter> configuration)
{
    // Each contribution to an ordered configuration has a name,
    // When necessary, you may set constraints to precisely control
    // the invocation order of the contributed filter within the pipeline.

    configuration.add("DeprecatedURLs", new RequestFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean service(Request request,
                               Response response,
                               RequestHandler handler) throws IOException
        {
            String path = request.getPath();
            if (isDeprecated(path))
            {
                response.sendError(404, "Not found");
                return;
            }

            return handler.service(request, response);
        }
    }, "before:*");
}
```

Notice the `before:*` ordering constraint, it should register this filter as the first in [`RequestHandler`'s configuration](http://tapestry.apache.org/request-processing.html#RequestProcessing-Overview).

Comment: I don't see anything like AppModule or RequestHandler in that legacy application code. I really don't know anything about tapestry. I just see TapestryFilter configured in my web.xml file something like this.          
           <filter>
  <filter-name>ResourcesApp</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ResourcesApp</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: It should be `ResourcesAppModule` instead of `AppModule`, because your filter is name `ResourcesApp`. If you don't know Tapestry and don't want to learn a bit for the task in your "legacy" app, you can always setup HTTP proxy like Apache or NGINX in front of your app and handle those deprecated URLs there.

Comment: sorry forgot to ask, which tapestry version do you have?